# Multiple IR Sensors with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, ir, audio

I am fairly new to working with sensors and Arduino. I am working on a project using Max MPS to control the volume of three audio files. There will be three framed photos, each having its own IR sensor and audio file. So when someone gets closer to the sensor, the volume of the corresponding file gets louder. Is this doable? The samples I have seen with the board I have and an IR sensor only use one. I'm assuming I'll be able to use the breadboard I have to add more sensors like I've done in the past with photocell sensors but I have yet to test it since it's in the mail. Just hoping to get ahead of any issues I may face and see if I should order any other equipment.

I ordered 3 of these [IR sensors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WQWHNDW) and this is the [Arduino kit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/193) I am working with.

Sorry if I may not be describing it in enough detail, but thanks in advance!

[image: Arduino Board example]

Comment: Yes, doable. Though the range will depend on the sensors. Do you have any other question, that is not just a yes-no question?

Answer (score 3):

technically yes, there is no reason you can't do that project but the issues will come in how complex you wish to make system. For example, it shouldn't be too hard to hook up the three sensors to three analogue Pins on the Arduino and then have the Arduino constantly loop to check the voltage of the sensors, from which, you would tell it to 'do something' when one of the IR sensors voltage is above or below a certain value. What you then choose to do is up to you, if it's just to turn on a light then it can be done fairly quickly once you have all the components. For controlling the Audio in the file, I personally have no experience with this.

What might be better is first checking to see if you can Adjust the audio in one of your files using an Arduino (you may need to use bluetooth or have something on your PC communicate with your Arduino via UART through the USB).

Generally, with new projects, it's a good idea to figure out a solid plan for exactly what you want to do, so I would write down in detail what you want the system to do and then go through each part to see if it's possible